# telprompt: Removing extension no from alert and call log of phone

Tags: ios, iphone, url-scheme, telprompt

I am trying to make a call through the telpromt command  to return to my application after it makes a call:

```
NSString *telno = @"telprompt://121,,,,14";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:telno]];
```

It shows an alert view showing which number I am calling. For above code it shows "121,,,,14" in alertview and recent call log of Phone. I have found some app, they does not show extension number, they only show "121" in alertview for example and in call log it shows "App Name" as dialed contact and "121" as dialed number. [Actually that app programetically adds a contact named "App Name" with main no "121" for example]. Is there any way to remove extension number [for example ",,,,14"] from alert and call log of phone?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `telprompt`, just display a normal `UIAlertView` with a cancel and call button.
Then when you have full control over the message in the `UIAlertView`, if the user choices call just use the `tel` scheme.

Also `telprompt` is not an official scheme, thus Apple can remove it in any future version of iOS.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I need to return to app which is not possible if I use "tel".

Comment: Then there is not option but to use the `telprompt`, just be aware that with notice this scheme might not work anymore. Since it is not official supported by Apple.